# Clicks triggers event too many times - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click

I have some special pb : I create on the fly by ajax request some lists and divs of class 'myclass', then on click on them, I call this wich adds some url in an input area and then adds some source to an iframe, displaying in a popup

```
$(document).on("click", "li .myclass", function () {
    var uri = $(this).closest('li').attr("id");
    var embed = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/';
    $('#myinput').val(val + uri);
    $('#wrapper iframe').attr('src', embed + uri);
});
```

Then on a click on a popup's button, I trigger a click on **#mybutton**, that create some text-zone

```
$(document).on("click", ".popup button", function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#mybutton').trigger('click');
    $('#myinput').val('');
});
```

My problem is that the first time I click on 'li .myclass' it creates cleanly one textzone. But if I click a second time, it creates three text zones, then if I click a third time, it creates 6 textzones. I really don't understand this brehavior, could someone help ?

Comment: Most likely you are binding your second piece of code on each click of #mybutton, resulting in duplicate bindings.

Comment: @KevinB in fact the extra textzone are created as soon as I click on 'li .myclass' ...

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing this:

```
$(document).on("click", "li .myclass", function () {
```

With this:

```
$("li .myclass").on("click", function () {
```

The way you're using the jQuery [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method with the 'selector' param is a little dangerous. It requires understanding of [Event Bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) and is a likely source of multiple events being triggered.

Comment: I have the same problem knowing that since I create my list on the fly  on() isn't trigering any event, so I tried with the deprecated live() (and it still doesn't work)

Comment: Creating dom elements on the fly and attaching events to them is a little tricky. You have to explicitly add the event handler to the new elements and be careful that you don't add duplicate event handlers to pre-existing elements. But afraid there's not a lot of info to go on in the question.

Answer (score 1):

We must to stopPropagation() In order to avoid Clicks triggers event too many times.

```
$(this).find('#cameraImageView').on('click', function(evt) {
evt.stopPropagation();
console.log("Camera click event.");
});
```